# Difference between at least and less than binomial probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Got a two part question given to me (I used binomial Distribution to solve)

> If the probability that an individual moves outside of his or her
>   country of residence in a given year is $0.12$, what is the probability
>   that less than $3$ out of a sample of $15$ move outside the country?

I approached it like this:

Less than three means $0$, $1$, or $2$.
The calculation for $0$ is:
$$
\frac{15!}{0!(15-0)!}0.12^0(1-.012)^15
$$

The calculation for $1$ is:
$$
\frac{15!}{1!(15-1)!}0.12^1(1-.012)^14
$$

The calculation for $2$ is:
$$
\frac{15!}{2!(15-2)!}0.12^2(1-.012)^13
$$

Now:

$$
P(X=0) \approx 0.147\\
P(X=1) \approx 0.300\\
P(X=2) \approx 0.287\\
P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2) \approx .3+.287+.147 \approx .734
$$
I am assuming that unless I botched the math then it should be correct.

The second question however asks

> "At least two move out of the country"

I am struggling to see the difference here, I know they are different however my question is, how do I go about solving the second one? Do  I just use $P(X=2)$ as my answer?

Any help would be appreciated,

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At least two* means $2,3,4,\ldots,13,14$, or $15$; you could work it the same way, but you’d have $14$ terms to compute and add up. It’s easier to notice that *at least two* covers all possibilities **except** $0$ and $1$. Calculate the probability that fewer than $2$ move, and subtract that from $1$.

Comment: Ok great, did I do the first bit correctly too? Never seem to be confident when doing statistics

Comment: @Sim: I didn’t check the actual arithmetic, but the method is correct.

Comment: Yeah if the method is correct then I'm sure my math is fine, Cheers